# HTTPS redirect to specific URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the below redirect set in httpd.conf which redirects subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/topics/apps

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [OR]<br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.domain.com.gov$<br>
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/topics/apps[R=301]
```

But if i try the same with https, it wont redirect to that page but shows domain.com homepage (not redirect). I guess this is because the DNS entry for subdomain.domain.com is also having the same IP as domain.com.

Can you guys suggest fixing this https redirect to http://domain.com/topics/apps.

Thanks,
Sudeer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a Virtual Host on Port 443 and also set it to Named Virtual Hosts when the IP is the same but the names are different.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.de
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 0  

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.domain.com.gov$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/topics/apps[R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that Apache, by default, handles SSL with a separate `VirtualHost` on a different port. Look for the `VirtualHost` which is listening on `443` and set the redirection there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the Vhosts ?  If so, I would skip the rewrites and simply do this(and restart httpd):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.com
  ServerAdmin you@you.com
  DocumentRoot this/needs/to/exist
  Redirect permanent / http://domain.com/topics/apps
</VirtualHost>
```